# «Porque» después de «inclinarse por»

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, preposiciones, conjunciones

Según este [enlace](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=porque), la conjunción **que** debe ir separada de **por** cuando el verbo exija esa preposición. Como ejemplo pongo el verbo **inclinarse por**:

> Me inclino por que estés aquí.
>   Se inclinaba por que el azul fuese el color elegido.

Personalmente no puedo hacer la distinción en cuanto al sentido si cambio **por que** por **porque**. Sigo con los dos ejemplos:

> Me inclino porque estés aquí.
>   Se inclinaba porque el azul fuese el color elegido.

Por tanto mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Es ambigua la distinción en estos ejemplos entre **por que** y **porque**?
2. ¿Tiene sentido construir una frase que indique una causa (que deberá ser introducida por **porque**) después del verbo **inclinarse por**?

Comment: Éste es un caso de la habitual confusión del uso de "que". No es una conjunción aquí, como dices, sino un pronombre relativo. Es conjunción causal en _"apúrate que estamos atrasados"_ y conjunción copulativa en _"llueve que lleve"_. Lamentablemente la palabra tiene muchos usos distintos (25 para ser precisos) y es la principal formadora de frases preposicionales, frases adverbiales y oraciones subordinadas. Por lo tanto mueve a confusión en la redacción y sobre todo en el aprendizaje de español como segunda lengua. Y es la tercera palabra más frecuente del español, después de "de" y "la".

Comment: Una pista: si hay un verbo en subjuntivo (como en tus ejemplos _estés_ y _fuese_), justo antes debe ir la palabra _que_ (o _quien, como, cuando, cuanto, donde_). Entonces el ejemplo "Me inclino porque estés aquí" es incorrecto, porque no está ninguna de esas palabras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Por** es una preposición con muchísimas funciones. En este caso la estás usando como "a favor de":

> Me inclino **por** guardarlos.
>
> Me inclino **por** que los guardemos.
>
> Me inclino **a favor de** que los guardemos.

En el segundo caso usamos un **que** para subordinar la oración "los guardemos". Puede quedarte claro que son palabas separadas si haces una perífrasis como ésta:

> Me inclino **por** la opción de **que** los guardemos.

En cambio **porque** es una conjunción que indica que lo anterior es la consecuencia y lo posterior es la causa.

> Me inclino **porque** no alcanzo a ver desde esta posición.
>
> Me inclino **pues** no alcanzo a ver desde esta posición.
>
> Me inclino **a causa de que** no alcanzo a ver desde esta posición.
>
> No alcanzo a ver desde esta posición, **por lo tanto**, me inclino. [inverso]

**Edición:**

Con respecto al ejemplo de **porque** que tú propones:

> Me inclino **porque** estés aquí.

no es una oración aceptable:

Como puse más arriba, la conjunción *porque* indica causa. El significado aquí entonces sería "*la causa es que estés aquí; la consecuencia es que me inclino*". No estoy seguro, pero no creo que sea esa la intención de la frase, me parece extraña. De hecho, como indicas, el significado comunicado no es una *causa*, sino una *preferencia*.

Y el *porque*, al ser una conjunción, une dos elementos con un equivalente valor sintáctico. En este caso, tendrían que ser dos oraciones independientes, cada una con un verbo nuclear en modo indicativo. Fíjate en el segundo verbo:

> [incorrecto] Me inclino porque **estés** aquí.
>
> [ correcto ] Me inclino porque **estás** aquí.

La segunda oración está correcta sintácticamente, pero no corresponde a lo que quieres comunicar. Si quieres usar una conjunción entre dos oraciones, ambas tienen que estar en el mismo modo (indicativo: *inclino-estás*), porque ambas oraciones tienen la misma "importancia sintáctica".

En cambio, en la oración que tú propones, hay un verbo en indicativo (*inclino*) y otro verbo en subjuntivo (*estés*). Esto pasa cuando hay una oración principal (la del indicativo) y otra oración secundaria subordinada (la del subjuntivo) que sirve de "apoyo" a la principal.

La oración principal es "Me inclino por X". Ese X se puede reemplazar por muchas cosas subordinadas, que sintácticamente funcionen como sustantivo, terminen el complemento encabezado por "por" y que indiquen la preferencia que quieres comunicar:

> Me inclino por **María**. [un sustantivo]
>
> Me inclino por **un helado de chocolate**. [una frase nominal]
>
> Me inclino por **trabajar este domingo**. [una subordinada sustantiva de infinitivo]
>
> Me inclino por **que estés aquí**. [una subordinada sustantiva de completivo]

Si lo tuyo es esto último, entonces el verbo va en subjuntivo (porque es una subordinada) y la construcción va encabezada obligatoriamente por un "que" (o alguna otra palabra con esa función, hay otras). No es posible usar un subjuntivo sin encabezar la oración con un "que".

Entonces "Me inclino porque estés aquí" es incorrecto porque no lleva ese "que".

Comment: En el último párrafo de ejemplos, ese **me inclino** tiene diferente significado que el que pongo en mi ejemplo (elegir una opción entre varias), por tanto, sí tiene sentido poner **porque** después. Ahora, ¿puede construir una oración con **inclinarse por** con el sentido que expongo junto con **porque**?

Comment: No puedo construir una oración como la que pides, pero edité la respuesta para explicar por qué. Perdona el palabreo.

Comment: Se podría construir una oración negativa: *no me inclino porque estés aquí*. Es decir: la razón de que me incline no es que estés aquí. En cambio, si la oración es afirmativa, hay que usar el indicativo y no el subjuntivo, como bien explica Rodrigo en su respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

¿Ambiguo?  No, ni en la lengua oral.

Hay que tomar en cuenta que *por que* es la preposición *por* seguido por el pronombre relativo *que*.  En esta construcción, no es nada diferente que otras preposiciones seguidas por *que* (*a que*, *de que*, *para que*, *con que* …).

Cuando dices *me inclino por [algo]*, a pesar de que normalmente ese *[algo]* suele ser un sustantivo, si lo que queremos mostrar nuestra preferencia es una cláusula entera, lo ponemos encabezado con *que*:

- Me inclino por [salir con vosotros].
- Me inclino por [el bar en el centro].
- Me inclino por [que salgamos al bar en el centro]

Nota que es muy normal el uso de subjuntivo en la cláusula sustantival, ya que nuestra inclinación demuestra una preferencia, así obligando su uso.

Pero hay dos de estas preposiciones que se han fusionado con el *que* para hacer un coordinador (o conjunción, según terminología).  *Porque* es uno de estos, que significa *por causa o razón de que* (y también *para que*, aunque este ultimo queda casi en desuso).<sup>1</sup>

*Porque* coordina una segunda cláusula ordinal, por lo tanto, solo le sigue una cláusula con su verbo en indicativo (excepto cuando significa *para que*, en tal caso, se usa obligatoriamente el subjuntivo).  Así que, con *inclinarse por*, será evidente la diferencia por el modo del verbo en la cláusula siguiente.

No hay problema en usar *porque* después de *inclinarse*, pero a menos que primero pongas otro *por* con lo que estés prefiriendo, alguien lo entenderá en el sentido de posicionar el cuerpo.

- Me inclino por [mi preferencia]. <sub>(sentido mostrar preferencia)</sub>
- Me inclino por [mi preferencia] porque [la razón es …]. <sub>(sentido mostrar preferencia)</sub>
- Me inclino por [que algo sea] porque [la razón es …]. <sub>(sentido mostrar preferencia)</sub>
- Me inclino porque [la razón es …] <sub>(sentido movimiento físico)</sub>

---

<sup>1. La otra preposición que quedó fusionado con *que* es *con*.  *Conque* significa *por lo tanto*, pero al principio de oraciones puede indicar sorpresa.</sup>